# SPARK Performance degrades with incremental loads in local mode

Tags: apache-spark

i am trying to run a apache spark sql job (1.6) in local mode over 3 node cluster and i face below issues in production.

1. Execution time for duplication layer is increasing day by day after incremental load at DL layer.
2. Nearly 150K records are being inserted in each table every day.
3. We have tried with default as well as “MEMORY AND DISK” persist mechanism , but its working same in both cases.
4. Execution time is impacting the other tables if we run large tables first.

spark job is being invoked in a standard format and executed  shell script using spark-submit and below sql query from my spark job is as below.

```
val result=sqlcontext.sql("CREATE TABLE "+DB+"."+table_name+" row format delimited fields terminated by '^' STORED as ORC tblproperties(\"orc.compress\"=\"SNAPPY\",\"orc.stripe.size\"='67108864') AS select distinct a.* from "+fdl_db+"."+table_name+" a,(SELECT SRL_NO,MAX("+INC_COL+") as incremental_col FROM "+fdl_db+"."+table_name+" group by SRL_NO) b where a.SRL_NO=b.SRL_NO and a."+INC_COL+"=b.incremental_col").repartition(100);
```

please let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: @all can anyone please have a look at this issue and suggest me with some approach to try out

Comment: Did you tried to partition the table and run stats on hive level?